# How can I delete a Stack Exchange account of mine?

Tags: support, accounts, deleted-users

I have an account on some Stack Exchange sites. I would like to remove one or more of my accounts. What is the process to delete my account(s)?

Answer (score 25):

You can find this information on the Help Center page: **[How do I delete my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)**

However, this does not apply to Area 51 yet. The workaround can be found in [Tim Post's answer to a question on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237691/how-to-delete-other-stackexangearea-51-account/237692#237692).

Comment: But this deletes the user profile not just one account am I right?

Comment: @Shayan No, you are wrong. This deletes just the profile of the Stack Exchange you are in, for example if you are in Politics Stack Exchange, then it will delete only the profile on the Politics Stack Exchange. And you will have 24 hours to cancel this if you already had some reputation points in it.

Comment: @Shayan I answered with some screenshots to prove this since from reading that help center link quickly, I could not be sure that it is just one profile in one chosen Stack Exchange that would get deleted.

Answer (score -3):

This is the accepted answer in screenshots, to delete just the profile of a chosen Stack Exchange, here: Politics.

I thought this could be helpful since from a quick read of that help center link, I could not be sure that it is just one profile in one chosen Stack Exchange that would get deleted.

I wanted to get rid of only the Politics profile since I had added it by mistake. This answer shows that you delete only a profile of a chosen Stack Exchange, not your "overall profile/user/account/user profile" or whatever this is called (the wording is unclear).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since did not have any reputation points in the Politics Stack Exchange (+100 came as the starting bonus), the Politics profile was deleted at once. If you had reputation points, you would have 24 hours to cancel the deletion.

Comment: The help center already covers this...

Comment: @Cerbrus That link starts with: `How do I delete my account? User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.` Which reads as if you deleted your user, not just a profile on some Stack Exchange. I also followed the help center. There was a comment asking `But this deletes the user profile not just one account am I right?`, some people do not seem to be 100 percent sure whether it is the profile of a chosen Stack Exchange (like for example Politics) or the whole Stack Exchange profile that gets deleted.

Comment: There is an unclear wording of "user" and "profile" and "account", you do not know just from reading these words what is meant. And the example in the help center goes on with deleting a profile from Stack Overflow. Which is the largest Stack Exchange and often seen as the name for the whole Stack Exchange. that is why it is not clear enough. I only knew from the last passage `Otherwise, your profile will be scheduled for deletion in 24 hours.` that I can change it back anyway, and only then, I dared to delete the profile.

Comment: @questionto42 Sounds like you want to submit a feature request with updated wording to clarify the help center. I'd suggest doing it on MSE.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I don't know why SO has decided to make this so confusing, now my concern is, when I delete my profile on a community can I create a new profile on there and start fresh? I'd really love to do that. And I was wondering if I would still get the default +100 reputation that you get when joining new communities on the new profile as well. If so, isn't that a loophole? You can ask questions, start a bounty on it, delete your profile and repeat! That would be broken!

Comment: @KevinB Made a question on MSE at [Unclear wording and missing screenshots in: "How do I delete my account?" Should be clearer that it is just one out of many profiles to be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387107/unclear-wording-and-missing-screenshots-in-how-do-i-delete-my-account-should).

Comment: @Shayan it is not a loophole. You can just start a new one when the old one was dropped. You also get the +100 bonus, and you will have any items you know from any other new profile. No punishment or anything else. Your actions of the old profile will be anonymised.

Answer (score -11):

Go to that particular community, click on your profile icon, select delete account. Read the disclaimer that this only deletes you from THAT community, and that you understand you have to do this with each community you want to leave. Immediate removal from that community may not happen right away based on your activity there.

Comment: From the amount of downvotes I reckon it is not possible to delete just one individual sub-account while keeping the rest of the accounts on the network intact?

Comment: @Shayan wrong. You can just delete a profile. It still is good that you ask. It was downvoted since everything was already in the accepted answer. I have just added another answer with screenshots and got downvoted for the same sake. That has a link to the help center. Yet, I think that this help center link is a bit unclear, therefore, the many downvotes are not understandable. It works as it is written here. Upvote.